# What equivalent adjustNothing for the lower API 11?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

What equivalent adjustNothing  for the lower API  11?

This command in manifest : android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"

This command as java code: 
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);

For continue my previous question:
[How to prevent lifting listview when keyboard goes up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199252/how-to-prevent-lifting-listview-when-keyboard-goes-up)

I'm solved the problem, using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" , but only for api higher 10. 
How solve this for api lower 11?

Comment: try to add in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(48);
```

works for me in Android 2.3